# How to control the error rate when selecting the mode of a sample as the mode of the population?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, poisson-distribution, ranking, post-hoc

I just looked out of my window and saw 4 white, 2 black, 1 green, 1 silver, 1 light blue, 1 lemon and 1 orange-white-striped car. Based on this, how confident should I be that white is the most common color for cars around here?

---

More formally, let $G$ be a probability distribution over some unknown space $\mathbb{S}$.
Given a sample $S^N$ of $G$ with size $N$, I would like to estimate the probability that most common observed outcome $\hat{s}(S^N) := \operatorname*{argmax}\limits_{s \in \mathbb{S}}{\sum^N_{i=1} \mathbb{I}[s=S^N_i]}$ is equal to the true mode of $G$, $s^* := \operatorname*{argmax}\limits_{s \in \mathbb{S}} p_{G}(\mathcal{S} = s) $.

However, since I cannot come to an agreement with reviewer #3 on what constitutes as a proper [not in the statistical sense] prior for $G$, all I can probably hope for is a procedure that makes an error only at pre-specified rate, $\alpha$, no matter what $G$ is, by making no decision if unsure but as rarely as possible:

Find a procedure $\tau : S^N \to \{true, false\}$ that decides whether $\hat{s}(S^N)$ should be accepted as estimate for $s^*$ such that the rate of making an error (wrongly accepting $\hat{s}$) is controlled (
$P_{G^N}(\tau(S^N) \land \hat{s}(S^N) \neq s^*) \leq \alpha$),
while maximizing the rate of making any decision
$P_{G^N}(\tau(S^N))$). Note that maximizing the decision rate beyond $\alpha$ requires making correct estimates. For each $G$ a differnt $\tau$ might be optimal. I know, there is no free lunch but a $\tau$ that is good for any $G$ would be nice; or at least one that is not dominated by another.

---

Several fields answer related but different questions:
Good-Turing estimators and the related field tries to estimate the probability of observing a new outcome in the next observation (a different color) or the total probability mass of yet unobserved colors.
Ranking and Selection procedures usually assume known $\mathbb{S}$ and adjust the sample size to obtain a desired error rate assuming a minimal difference of the mode to the second "best" ("indifference zone") or select multiple possible outcomes ("subset selection", (Gupta & co)).
ANOVA (Hypothesis test for heterogeneity paired with post hoc-testing) usually compares individual outcomes/ means, not all against all others. The naive strategy of combining all pairwise tests with multiple testing correction seems to be overly conservative. (& does not work with unknown $\mathbb{S}$)

Comment: I'm having a hard time seeing how it would be possible to *control* the error rate. What estimator would you use other than the sample mode (or a random selection among all modes, when they are multiple)? The best you can hope for is to report some estimate of the error rate.

Comment: @whuber This should be possible "by making no decision if unsure" which I would count to "not making an error" (Sorry for not being clear about this; any idea how to rephrase?). For example, one albeit useless procedure that achieves such an error rate control (at alpha=0) is one that never makes a decision. A better one would select the mode if the outcome makes up more than 80% of the observations and was observed at least 40 times. The latter would control the error rate I believe roughly at least at $P_{Binom}(k=10|n=50,p=0.5)≈0.001111$.

Comment: Your comment points out the importance of providing us a *loss function:* you need to specify, numerically, how much we should penalize wrong decisions. Obviously you also need to enumerate the set of possible decisions, too.  Without a loss function there is no way to distinguish the useless "I can't decide" procedure from any other procedure.

Comment: @whuber I believe the loss is hidden in "but [is making no decision] as rarely as possible" but i will try to make this more explicit.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out.  That phrase certainly hints at a loss, but does not fully specify it, because we still don't know how to balance the risks of various possible errors, including (a) making no decision when you should have; (b) making a decision when you should not have; (c) identifying the mode incorrectly.

Comment: @whuber I added another paragraph to specify more precisely what I hope for. Let me know how I can improve the notation if unclear. The idea is similar to hypothesis tests: the loss for false negatives (="not deciding") is constant while the loss for false positives (="falsely accepting the mode estimate") is zero if its expected to happen less than $\alpha$ and $\infty$ otherwise (and 0 for true positives ("correctly accepting")).